# How to hide css div using the HTML select option in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am a beginner in jQuery. I am trying to develop an interest calculator maximum tasks are complete. But I am facing a simple issue. while I will select the month **Minter** class will appear on the screen and the **inter** class will disappear. In the same way while I will select the year **inter** class will appear on the screen and the **Minter** class will disappear.I cant fix this. Please can help me how to fix it?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"\>\</script\>
 <script>

       function thousands_separe(num)
        {
          let number = num.toString().split(".");
          number[0] = number[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
          return number.join(".");
        }

       $(function() {
       $("#invest, #ratereturn, #term").on("keyup", function(){ 

            let invest = $('#invest').val();
            let ratereturn = $('#ratereturn').val();
            let term = $('#term').val();
            let duration = $('#duration').val();
            let interest = Math.pow((1+ratereturn/100),term); 

            let minterest = Math.pow((1+ratereturn/100/12),term); 

            let total = invest * interest;
            let decitotal1 = total.toFixed(); 
            let intotal = thousands_separe(decitotal1);
   
            $('#total').html(intotal);
            $('#inter').html(interest);
            $('#Minter').html(minterest);



        });
      }); 



    </script>

<p>Beginning Investment</p> 
<input type="text" id="invest" name="invest" width="200" value="1000"></br>

<p>Rate of Return</p> 
<input type="text" id="ratereturn" id="ratereturn" width="200" value="10"></br>

<p>Term Length</p> 
<input type="text" id="term" id="term" width="200" value="10"></br>

<p>duration</p> 

 <select id="duration" id="duration"> 
          <option selected> Year</option>
          <option> Month</option>  
 </select>

<p>Total: $<span id="total"></span></p>

<p>Year Interest: $<span id="inter"></span></p>

<p>Month Interest: $<span id="Minter"></span></p>
```

Yes, I tried to fix this but i cant recognise how to fix this. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

HTML:

```
<p>Beginning Investment</p> 
<input type="text" id="invest" name="invest" width="200" value="1000"></br>

<p>Rate of Return</p> 
<input type="text" id="ratereturn" id="ratereturn" width="200" value="10"></br>

<p>Term Length</p> 
<input type="text" id="term" id="term" width="200" value="10"></br>

<p>duration</p> 

 <select id="duration" id="duration"> 
          <option value="year" selected> Year</option>
          <option value="month"> Month</option>  
 </select>

<p>Total: $<span id="total"></span></p>

<p class="inter interest_value active">Year Interest: $<span id="inter"></span></p>

<p class="Minter interest_value">Month Interest: $<span id="Minter"></span></p>
```

Css:

```
.interest_value {
  display:none;
}
.interest_value.active {
  display: block
}
```

Jquery:

```
 function thousands_separe(num)
        {
          let number = num.toString().split(".");
          number[0] = number[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
          return number.join(".");
        }

       $(function() {
       $("#invest, #ratereturn, #term").on("keyup", function(){ 

            let invest = $('#invest').val();
            let ratereturn = $('#ratereturn').val();
            let term = $('#term').val();
            let duration = $('#duration').val();
            let interest = Math.pow((1+ratereturn/100),term); 

            let minterest = Math.pow((1+ratereturn/100/12),term); 

            let total = invest * interest;
            let decitotal1 = total.toFixed(); 
            let intotal = thousands_separe(decitotal1);
   
            $('#total').html(intotal);
            $('#inter').html(interest);
            $('#Minter').html(minterest);



        });
      }); 
    $("#duration").on("change", function(){ 
        let val = $(this).val();
        if(val === "year") {
           $(".interest_value").removeClass("active");
            $(".inter").addClass("active");
        }else {
         $(".interest_value").removeClass("active");
         $(".Minter").addClass("active")
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks that is working properly. But got another problem, First loading Month div dont show. But year div will be show. User can change as desired by selecting option. can you tell me.

Comment: I have updated the code.. please check.. I am not 100% sure what exactly you want to achieve.. But I think it will work.

Comment: thanks your first script was good. Just i was wrongly present & get the wrong result.

$(function() { 
        $("#Mitotal").hide();

        $("#duration").on("change", function(){ 
            let value = $(this).val();
        //console.log(value)
                    if(value === "Year") {
             console.log(value)
                $("#Mitotal").hide();
                $("#ytotal").show();
            }else{
                   console.log(value)
            $("#ytotal").hide();
            $("#Mitotal").show();
            }
        });